# How to format text as currency

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a plugin that formats numbers as currency, by inserting decimal & thousands separators:

```
1000     -> 1.000
10000,5  -> 10.000,5
```

and I call it like this:

```
$('#input').myPlugin()
```

But I want to call it by specifying the characters to use for the decimal and thousands separators:

```
$('#input').myPlugin({thousand_type: ',' , decimal_type '.'}).
```

How can I accomplish that in my plugin?

---

Here's the plugin:

```
(function( $ ){

  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
    $('input').keypress(function(event){
        if ((event.which  < 48 || event.which  > 57) && event.which  != 8 && event.which  != 44)
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    $('input').keyup(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();  

        val = $(this).val();

        if(val != ''){
            thousand_type = '.';        
            if(thousand_type == '.'){
                decimal_type = ',';
            }else{
                decimal_type = '.';
            }

            //remove thousand mark
            if(thousand_type == '.'){
                val = String(val).replace(/\./g, "");
            }else{
                val = String(val).replace(/\,/g, "");
            }

            //get position of decimal mark
            pos_decimal = String(val).indexOf(decimal_type);

            //device the number to thousand and decimal
            if(pos_decimal > -1){
                sub_decimal = String(val).substring(pos_decimal, String(val).length);
                sub_thousand = String(val).substring(0, pos_decimal);
            }else{
                sub_decimal = '';
                sub_thousand = val;
            }
            //1.111.111,33
            //remove decimal mark
            if(decimal_type == '.'){
                removed_mark_val = String(val).replace(/\./g, "");
            }else{
                removed_mark_val = String(val).replace(/\,/g, "");
            }

            //check is Numeric
            result = IsNumeric(removed_mark_val);

            if(result == true){
                if(thousand_type == '.'){
                    sub_thousand = String(sub_thousand).split("").reverse().join("")
                      .replace(/(.{3}\B)/g, "$1" + thousand_type)
                      .split("").reverse().join("");
                }else{              
                    sub_thousand = String(sub_thousand).split("").reverse().join("")
                      .replace(/(.{3}\B)/g, "$1" + thousand_type)
                      .split("").reverse().join("");
                }
                val = sub_thousand + sub_decimal;
                //1111111,33
                $(this).attr('value',val);  
            }else{

            }
        }
    });
    function IsNumeric(input){
        var RE = /^-{0,1}\d*\.{0,1}\d+$/;
        return (RE.test(input));
    }
  };
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a plugin I wrote (319 bytes minified):

```
(function($)
{
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options)
    {
        options = $.extend({
            thousands: ',',
            decimal: '.'
        }, options);

        return this.keyup(function()
        {
            $(this).val(function(el, val)
            {
                val = val.replace(/[^\d.,]/g, '').split(options.decimal);
                val[0] = val[0].replace(options.decimal === '.' ? /,/g : /\./g, '');
                val[0] = val[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, "$1" + options.thousands);
                return val.join(options.decimal);
            });
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Use it like this:

```
$('input').myPlugin({
    thousands: '.',
    decimal: ','
});
```

See it here in action: http://jsfiddle.net/yywc7/

---

**Note:** this still needs some work, as the arrow keys are pretty messed up. I use it in my projects with the plugin tying into the `blur` event. But since you seem to want it on `keyup`, it needs some work to play nice with the arrow keys.

Comment: Thank you for helping me ^^ . I want to Vote for you but i'm not enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass parameters to your jQuery plugin, simply accept parameters to your plugin function.

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function(opts) {

    ...

    if (opts.thousands_type == ',') {

    ...
```

[See here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Defaults_and_Options) for more information.